# How to calculate difference between two group values in MS Access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I'm working on a MS Access report where I need to find the difference between two numerical values that are grouped together(name of the group is RESULT TYPE which have two values 'Before the meeting' and 'After the meeting' ). My report looks like this:

BEFORE THE MEETING: 60%

AFTER THE MEETING: 80%

Is it possible to come up with a formula inside the report header that will show the difference between results "after the meeting" and results "before the meeting"? The formula used to get to "before/after" values is an average of the results values inside of the IIF statement. 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. But since you're not providing the code for those first aggregates, we can only guess about how to calculate the difference between them.

Comment: Perhaps repeat the same IIf() expressions in the header textbox as terms of subtraction.

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting, the problem is how do I distinguish between "before" and "after" values? I group my results using a column that contains either "Before..". or "After..." string.Then results are displayed using an IIF() statement.